# Lock one view orientation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, uideviceorientation

I'm trying to lock one view of my app in portrait mode. I have a top navigation controller view and multiple nested scenes.

I found many answers to lock orientation question and tried the code below, but it works only partially. Let the scenes A and B, where A has a `segue` to B, and B is locked in portrait orientation. If I go to the B scene, turn the device to the landscape position and back to A, the orientation is inherited from previous B (portrait).

How can I make the A scene recognize the actual device orientation?

#### Navigation controller

```
internal override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return visibleViewController!.shouldAutorotate()
}
```

#### "B" View controller

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation == .Portrait {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let orientation = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(orientation, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

Comment: Check out my answer and give me feedback if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want to know how to get the current device orientation.

Try this...

```
var orientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Once I set the orientation in `viewDidLoad`, I lost this functionality.